# Where is zero degrees on a graph

Tags: trigonometry

I am using the following formula to calculate the position of a point after rotation in my web application.

```
x' = xcos(0) - ysin(0)
y' = xsin(0) + ycos(0)
```

But where on a graph is zero degrees in Mathematics? **In the following image can you tell me where zero degrees is(is it at Point A or Point B?)** If it turns out that zero degrees is at point B then I will need to add 90 degrees to all my degree values in order to use the above function, correct?

[image]

Comment: Usually it's at $B$.

Comment: @Rasmus thanks, so if it was B I would need to add 90(or is it minus) degrees to my angle to use that math function? Ie, because my program considers zero degrees from point A, if I use the formula I will be really working out a rotation for 135 degrees which will be incorrect wont it?

Comment: In trigonometry the argument of every direct trigonometric function, cosine, sine, etc. is the angle measured counterclockwise from the positive x-axis. See [this Wikipedia section](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_circle#Trigonometric_functions_on_the_unit_circle). So it corresponds to B.

Comment: Is there a connection between this question and [this other question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/122850/where-is-zero-degrees-on-a-graph) posted a quarter of an hour earlier? It sure looks like it; even the $\theta$ written like a $0$ is the same.

Answer (score 2):

The argument of the trigonometric functions in your formulas is not the absolute angle of a point but the relative angle by which the point $(x',y')$ is rotated with respect to the point $(x,y)$. Thus you don't need to know where the angle zero is in absolute terms; all you need to know is whether a positive angle represents a clockwise or a counterclockwise rotation. This you can find out e.g. by rotating the point $(1,0)$ by $\pi/2$ (or $90^\circ$); the result is $(0,1)$, so the rotation is counterclockwise.

If you do ever need to know where the angle $0$ is in absolute terms, it's usually taken to be along the positive $x$ axis, with positive angles between $0$ and $\pi/2$ representing points in the first quadrant, i.e. with positive $x$ and $y$ coordinates.

By the way, I disagree with your claim that "in programming, zero degrees is at point $A$". I think Java counts as programming, and it uses the mathematical convention, in which zero degrees corresponds to $B$; see e.g. [the API for java.awt.Graphics.drawArc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawArc%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29).